# Python removing substring

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove a list of words/phrases in a sentence.

```
sentence = 'hello thank you for registration'
words_to_remove=['registration','reg','is','the','in','payment','thank you','see all tags']

sentence = ' '.join([word for word in sentence.split() if word not in words_to_remove])
```

But this does not remove 'thank you' or 'see all tags'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the list of words and replace each word using [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace):

```
sentence = 'hello thank you for registration'
words_to_remove=['registration','reg','is','the','in','payment','thank you','see all tags']

for word in words_to_remove:
    sentence = sentence.replace(word, '')
```

At the end, `senctence` will hold the value:

```
>>> sentence
'hello  for '
```

Comment: I took ur answer because it was the earliest

Comment: @weizengJust for your info, you should not be accepting the answer which was earliest, but the one which best suits your problem and detailed information as it acts a reference for others referring in the future. Looks like here my answer satisfies those clauses as well ;)

Comment: Can add sentence = ' '.join(sentence.split()) at the end to tidy up extra space left from remove words

Comment: @Skycc Just for removing the space *why **.join()** and **.split()**?* do just `str.strip()`

Comment: Strip only remove both end space but not in the middle

Comment: @Skycc try it once :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in words_to_remove:
    sentence = sentence.replace(word, "")
```

Comment: Yes I think this is what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

Split 'thank you' in 'thank','you', because that happens when you split sentence.

```
>>> sentence = 'hello thank you for registration'
>>> words_to_remove=['registration','reg','is','the','in','payment','thank','you','see all tags']
>>> sentence = ' '.join([word for word in sentence.split() if word not in words_to_remove])
>>> sentence
'hello for'
>>>
```

Comment: I dont want to delete all the "you"... etc