# Remove substring from string if substring is contained in a list

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

**Problem:**
I have a string that has "tags" from a list called "listOfTags". If the string contains one of these "tags" from the list I want to be able to remove these "tags" from the string.

**What I tried:**
I  first tried traversing through "listOfTags" and appending each "tag" to an empty string variable called x. Then, I tried to remove the "tags" from another string variable called y by using the string.replace method.I then realized that this method would only return what I wanted if the "tags" appeared in the order that they were appended in the variable x.

**The algorithm I created is as follows:**

*if a string contains as a sub-string any strings specified in a particular list: 
    remove the substring from the string*

**An example of the problem:**

```py
listOFTags = ["#tag", "#bold", "#merge"] 

string = "#tag #bold bob #merge" 

#execute algorithm here
```

How do I get a string returned that has the text "bob"?

**What I want returned:**

```py
new_string = "bob"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python removing substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557936/python-removing-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are tens of tags and each string to process contains tens of words, it would be more efficient to use regular expressions for this task.

```
import re
p = re.compile('|'.join(listOFTags))  # p can be reused across different input strings
new_string = p.sub("", string).strip()
```

This solution works if the tags do not contain any characters that have special meanings in regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replace`:

```
listOFTags = ["#tag", "#bold", "#merge"]

string = "#tag #bold bob #merge"

for tags in listOFTags:
    string = string.replace(tags, "")

print(string)
```