# Build dataframe from python dictionary

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have the below python dictionary.The decimal values of the dict can change, but the string values remains constant. The structure of the dictionary also would be the same.
In such a scenario, is it possible to build a dataframe (in the format shown below) from the dictionary?

Python dictionary:

```
d1=
{'Type 1 Result': 'CO (mg/km) THC (mg/km) NMHC (mg/km) NOX (mg/km) THC + NOX (mg/km) PM (mg/km) PN (#.1011/km)  Measured(8) (9)  104.70  21.00  -  9.20  -  0.20  0.03 Ki x (8) (10) - - - - (11) - - Ki + (8) (10) 2.9541 0.1158 - 1.9789 (11) 0.0265 N/A Mean value calculated with Ki (M x Ki) or M+Ki) (9)   107.65   21.12   -   11.18   (12)   0.23   0.03 DF (+) (8) (10) 58.5770 - - 10.0990 5.0210 0.0000 0.0000 DF (x) (8) (10) - - - - - - - Final mean value calculated with Ki and DF (13)  166.2  21.1  -  21.3  37.3  0.23  0.03 Limit value 500 N/A N/A 80 170 4.5 6.0'}
```

Required Dataframe Format:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible. Because your dictionary does not contain more than 1 key / value pair, I would suggest to merge it into a string:

```
my_string = f"{list(d1.keys())[0]} {list(d1.values())[0]}"
```

Next, you can flag the "constant" values of columns and rows:

```
COL_ROWS = ["Type 1 Result", "CO \(mg/km\)", "THC \(mg/km\)", "NMHC \(mg/km\)", "NOX \(mg/km\)", "THC \+  PM \(mg/km\)", "PN \(#\.1011/km\)", "Measured\(8\) \(9\)", "Ki x \(8\) \(10\)", "Ki \+ \(8\) \(10\)", "Mean value calculated with Ki \(M x Ki\) or M\+Ki\) \(9\)", "DF \(\+\) \(8\) \(10\)", "DF \(x\) \(8\) \(10\)", "Final mean value calculated with Ki and DF \(13\)", "Limit value"]
```

Subsequently, if you remove the strings that appear in `COL_ROWS` from `my_string`. Using: [Remove substring from string if substring is contained in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57192979/remove-substring-from-string-if-substring-is-contained-in-a-list):

```
import re
p = re.compile('|'.join(COL_ROWS ))
my_string = p.sub("", my_string).strip()
```

You will obtain a string where each value is separated by a space. You can then simply do `elements = my_string.split()` to have them neatly in a list.

Finally, you simply have to implement the logic to initialize a DataFrame using that data by iterating over the columns and elements.

A possibility is:

```
# separate headers from content
COLS, CONTENT = COL_ROWS[:8], COL_ROWS[8:]
    
all_cols = {}
for i in range(len(CONTENT)):
    # store column name
    col = [CONTENT[i].replace('\\', '']
    # add values
    col += el[i * 7: (i+1) * 7]
    # store in dict
    all_cols[COLS[i]] = col

# initialize DF with dict
final_df = pd.DataFrame(all_cols)
```

Comment: Iam unable to remove the substrings(constant values) using the solution provided in the link.

Comment: Tried with the same code.its giving me the same string as the output  without removing the constants

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar indeed, you need to change the constants and add "\" before parentheses such that the regex picks up on them (later you will need to strip them from the names when building the frame).

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar, with my latest edit on COL_ROWS, you should have a working code.

Comment: how did you create the dataframe ? do you have any links/logic so that i can refer to the syntax

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar, I added the code to do it. Can you close this issue now?

Comment: Brilliant ! Modified the code a bit.It works as expected! thank you.

Comment: @JayashreeSridhar in that case, can you please flag my answer as being the correct one ?